# How to make a JQuery script that only submits when you put an exact url in

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So, i wrote a script that gos directy to any website if you type the exact url e.g https://google.com. But the problem it submits and when ever you put anything in the input feild. I only want the script to submit when you put an exact url (https://something.com). Heres the original script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){

            var url = document.getElementById("TextInput").value;

            window.open(url);
        });
    </script>
```

```
<input placeholder="Type a url.." id="TextInput" type="text">
<button id="myButton">
submit
</button>
```

Comment: That fiddle has absolutely nothing to do with what you are asking

Comment: @charlietfl Im sorry, i forgot to link the correct fiddle. I guess it didn't save or somthing, im new to working with Jsfiddles. I'll delete the link.

Comment: you could use `new URL` (in a try/catch) to check if the vlaue is a valid URL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a function that checks if the URL passed is valid.

```
function isValidUrl(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(str);
}

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){

  var url = document.getElementById("TextInput").value;

  if (isValidUrl(url)) {
    window.open(url);
  } else {
    // Do something if not valid
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to validate that a properly constructed url is input. This doesn't guarantee that the url exists on the web , just that it has a proper protocol, domain etc

```js
const urls = ['google.com', 'http://google.com','https://example.com'];

function isValidUrl(str) {
  try {
    const u = new URL(str);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

urls.forEach(str => console.log(str, isValidUrl(str)))
```

Answer (score -1):

- Use `type="button"` (otherwise by default type is `"submit"`!)

```js
const allowedURL = "https://google.com";

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var url = document.getElementById("TextInput").value.trim();
  const is_valid = url === allowedURL;
  console.log(is_valid);
  if (is_valid) window.open(url); // or use document.location =
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Type a url.." id="TextInput" type="text">
<button type="button" id="myButton">submit</button>
```

- To check if a URL is valid, use the [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL):

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL
function is_valid_URL(str) {
  try {
    new URL(str);
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const url = document.getElementById("TextInput").value.trim();
  const is_valid = is_valid_URL(url);
  console.log(is_valid);
  if (is_valid) window.open(url); // or use document.location =
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Type a url.." id="TextInput" type="text">
<button type="button" id="myButton">submit</button>
```